# Creating a list view item that holds both regular and bold text WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I have searched high and low but cannot find an exact match for my request. I am binding several objects as to a list view using the code below. The item FaultDescription is a string that describes the state of an item of machinery, including a brief description/title for the item. My question is - is there a way by which I can have the title in bold font followed by the rest of the text in regular font within the same item?

eg."**The Title** ......Here is the rest of the text......"

BTW I build the string using StringBuilder in the instance of the class that I am binding the listview to.

Many thanks,

Jeff

C#:

```
lstvProductFaultState.Items.Add(newFaultRecord);
```

XAML:

```
  <ListView FontSize="12" Height="252" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="251,261,0,0" 
         Name="lstvProductFaultState" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="717" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FaultNumber}" Header="No." Width="18" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Rating" Width="40">
                             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding FaultRatingImage}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Radius}" Header="Radius" Width="40" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Edge}" Header="Edge" Width="40" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FaultTitleAndDescription}" Header="Fault Details" Width="200" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Photo 1" Width="80">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Image1}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Photo 2" Width="80">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image2}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Photo 3" Width="80">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image3}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why your are sticking Title and other text together in the FaultDescription using StringBuilder? Can't you just bind Title and FaultDescription to a separate TextBlocks with different styles?

Comment: Thanks Piotr - I was doing that before but it just takes up too much horizontal space on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks Eirik that's a great idea - I'm a WPF newbie so never thought of that. I have tried that code and bound it to the title and description (these also are members of the class I have bound the listview to). The data does not appear in the stack panel text blocks. If I bind exactly the same data to a standard listview item the data appears. Do I need to bind the data differently to the stackpanel textblocks?